# TCP behavior on Mac OS vs Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, tcp

The following process results in different behavior in Mac OS and Ubutu:

```
cat some_text_file | xargs a_shell_script.sh

a_shell_script.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" | telnet 127.0.0.1 123
exit 0
```

The TCP server listening on port 123 is scripted to process the contents of some_text_file. On my Ubuntu implementation of this process the length of input that the TCP server receives is the length of the some_text_file. On my OSX implementation however - it is a smaller fraction of the length ie. the input gets truncated somehow.

Note: This is not an xargs issue as far as I can tell. The number of args (`$#`) available to `a_shell_script.sh` is equal in both implementation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing enough about the implementation, I can only assume that your process on the listening end doesn't loop to `recv(2)` from the socket, but only reads once. The fact that you get everything at once on Ubuntu and you don't on OS X probably has to do with the TCP stack implementation on the two systems, but it's not something that should matter; instead, the code on the receiving end should poll the socket and read data as available.

Check out the `socket(2)` and `recv(2)` calls, and maybe post some code if you think it would help.